# Using Multiple git URLs in the same Jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins

I am using git repositories in my Jenkins jobs. Now I would like to use second git URL for one of my new jobs. Can I use it?

Will it create any problems in my existing setup or workspace?

Any suggestions are welcome.